# Only storing 26th object under variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, it should store 26 different variables under the object GameThumbs for each of the 26 objects in `r.Showcase`
However, all that is stored is `Object {26: "http://t3.rbxcdn.com/1e2476473494bfb202592501a5f86655"}`

I don't see anything wrong with my code, please help me fix it. Thank you (sorry if I am not describing the problem well enough; my English is not very well)

```
function info(id) {
var User = {};
var GameIds = {};
var GameNames = {};
var GameThumbs = {};
$("html").html("");
$.get('http://api.roblox.com/Users/'+id, function(r) {
    User['Username'] = r.Username;
}).done(function() { 
    $.get('http://www.roblox.com/Contests/Handlers/Showcases.ashx?userId='+id, function(r) { 
        for (var x in r.Showcase) {
            GameIds[x] = r.Showcase[x]['ID'];
            GameNames[x] = r.Showcase[x]['Name'];
            var link = 'http://www.roblox.com/item-thumbnails?params=%5B%7BassetId:'+GameIds[x]+'%7D%5D';
            $.get(link, function(d) {
                GameThumbs[x] = d[0]['thumbnailUrl'];
            });
        }
    }).done(function() {
        console.log(User, GameIds, GameNames, GameThumbs);
    });
}); 
}
```

Requested sample JSON (of `link`)

```
[{"id":45778683,"name":"Temple of the Ninja Masters!","url":"/Temple-of-the-Ninja-Masters-place?id=45778683","thumbnailFinal":true,"thumbnailUrl":"http://t0.rbxcdn.com/6eb2d1f05d120757ae1e72d8e28c918e","bcOverlayUrl":null,"limitedOverlayUrl":null,"deadlineOverlayUrl":null,"limitedAltText":null,"newOverlayUrl":null,"imageSize":"large","saleOverlayUrl":null,"iosOverlayUrl":null,"transparentBackground":false}]
```

of /Contets/Handlers/Showcases.ashx...

```
{"Error" :"", "Count" :"43", "UserIsAtMaxShowcases":"false", "Showcase" : [{"ID":164081122,"Name":"For ShrekIetsky"}, {"ID":163393918,"Name":"N7"}, {"ID":162493258,"Name":"Hackathon 2014"}, {"ID":158445333,"Name":"bests kings"}, {"ID":157560077,"Name":"Don't be an idiot."}, {"ID":157183481,"Name":"Lots of Thumbnails"}, {"ID":156339175,"Name":"Watch out!"}, {"ID":155669451,"Name":"YES I AM BIASED"}, {"ID":155669434,"Name":"Place_4"}, {"ID":155669424,"Name":"Place_3"}, {"ID":155669403,"Name":"Place_2"}, {"ID":155669381,"Name":"Place_1"}, {"ID":153242188,"Name":"earth2noah"}, {"ID":152827982,"Name":"Buying Egg Merch?"}, {"ID":152563337,"Name":"Inside Mallowpuff's head"}, {"ID":151207481,"Name":"nothin to see here"}, {"ID":151117405,"Name":"Acronym test"}, {"ID":149734880,"Name":"TESTING"}, {"ID":146087560,"Name":"FPS maps"}, {"ID":144140735,"Name":"Old Memories"}, {"ID":144035150,"Name":"Quitting"}, {"ID":142668569,"Name":"Challange Projecto"}, {"ID":140204830,"Name":"Element Obby! [Beta]"}, {"ID":140201014,"Name":"NEVERMIND KIDS C:"}, {"ID":138010986,"Name":"Passage of the Mind"}, {"ID":138006022,"Name":"I see you"}, {"ID":135852345,"Name":"Trade Information!"}, {"ID":135303493,"Name":"Future project"}, {"ID":129885802,"Name":"ololwoaplsiaeo"}, {"ID":129768085,"Name":"SiIencedSong's Place Number: 16"}, {"ID":127537299,"Name":"olopio"}, {"ID":120338485,"Name":"LmaD building!"}, {"ID":120338432,"Name":"Maze Daze [INACTIVE]"}, {"ID":120338402,"Name":"Volcano Survival maps"}, {"ID":120338370,"Name":"[[OpenSource]]"}, {"ID":120338338,"Name":"Yes"}, {"ID":120338296,"Name":"No"}, {"ID":120338264,"Name":"hackathon0n stuff"}, {"ID":118933268,"Name":"-"}, {"ID":118932768,"Name":"Testing"}, {"ID":118573473,"Name":"ROBLOX fame HQ."}, {"ID":118324272,"Name":"Simple spawnroom"}, {"ID":117834273,"Name":"Lightningsurvivor's fort."}] }
```

Comment: Please post sample json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same old problem with asynchronous code.

When you iterate with `for...in`, `x` changes. When the callback function of `$.get` is called for the first time, `for` *has completed its iterations* and `x` now yields the last value of the iterations, which is presumably 26.

You have two solutions for this:

- make the `$.get` call synchronous (bad, never do this);
- create a closure for the iteration.

Using jQuery, for example:

```
$.each(r.Showcase, function(x) {
    ...
    $.get(link, function(d) {
        GameThumbs[x] = d[0]['thumbnailUrl'];
    });
});
```

instead of `for (var x in r.Showcase)`. This way, `x` is a local variable inside the callback function of `$.each`, and its value will be the same when returning from `$.get`.

Comment: I assumed it had to do with synchronicity, I just didn't know how to fix it. Thank you, will test this code

Comment: When I ran this, all of the variables returned undefined

Comment: I was still polishing the code. Try again. I made a small edit on `$.each`.

Comment: Wait, it's still saying the GameThumbs are undefined for some reason

Comment: If I keep var GameThumbs outside of the parameters of `info`, it works. If I keep it within, it says it is undefined

Comment: I replaced the console.log with `for (var y in GameIds) {
    var gameBox = '<div>'
    gameBox+='<p>'+GameNames[y]+'</p>';
    gameBox+='<img src="'+GameThumbs[y]+'">';
    gameBox+='<br /></div>'
    $(gameBox).appendTo("body")
   }` and it is returning GET http://www.roblox.com/my/messages/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: `User`, `GameIds`, `GameNames` and `GameThumbs` are all *local* variables scoped inside the function `info`. You won't simply get their contents if `info` doesn't return or store them somehow.

Comment: The code I just commented with is within the info scope, and everything about it works except for GameThumbs

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `GameThumbs` on the code. It' just that with that last `console.log` in the `done` callback you *won't* see it filled at that time, because the requests to `/item-thumbnails` aren't completed yet. You have to wait for *all* of them before seeing the complete result (hint: learn about `$.when` and deferred objects in jQuery). Finally, I suggest using arrays for all those variables (and adding new values with `push`), and never using `for...in` to iterate through arrays (like `r.Showcase`).